# Can WKWebView instance show webpage while it is loading?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I'm using WKWebView to browse the specific website. 
WKWebView instance loads initial page of the website by URL with method `load(_ request: URLRequest) -> WKNavigation?` Until load request isn't completed I see white screen. Can WKWebView show already loaded parts of the webpage while the rest of the webpage is loading?
Can UIWebView do this trick?

Comment: I think its depends weather the web support progressive loading or not, not the WKWebView itself?

Comment: @Tj3n, Do you mean web page itself? I don't know whether this feature is supported. It isn't my website. How can I check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if white screen is your issue, i recommend you to display an custom **progress indicator over the webView or some Animation view** over your webView.

Once the loading is completed hide the progress indicator.

**Start your Animation at:**

```
 optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
    didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)
{
//Start Progress indicator animation
}
```

**End/Hide your Animation/Progress View at:**

```
    optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, 
                didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
{
      //Stop Progress indicator animation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case progressive loading started to work when i have added delegate WKWebViewNavigationDelegate to WKWebview and function

`func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!)`

If this func was not added, Web page did not rendered before all content was downloaded in all cases